# Display the variable names of an array sort?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, console

** This is my first post on StackOverflow, and I code only in high school, so I am by no means a professional. I am in fact quite novice XD. What's also important to note is that I'm using ReadyToProgramInJava as my IDE, so I'm using the HSA Console to code my programs. Anyways, on with my question.

I'm coding a program that requires me to sort an int array, and then display the highest value within that array. I'm using array.sort to arrange the variables in ascending order, and then printing out the highest value of the array. Something like this:

```
public class stackOverflowQuestion


Console c;
public stackOverflowQuestion ()
{
    c = new Console ();
}


public void Sorting ()
{
int obi = 10;
int luke = 4;
int vader =21;
int palpatine = 5;
    int [ ] people = {obi, luke, vader, palpatine};
  Arrays.sort(people);    
  c.println (people [people.length - 1]);
}


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    stackOverflowQuestion s = new stackOverflowQuestion ();
    s.Sorting ();
}
```

The problem is this: When I print the highest value of the array, it displays only the number. So, if I were to run this program as it stands, it would output "21". Ideally, I'd like it to print the name of the variable with the highest value. So, upon running this program, I'd like it to print "Vader". Is there anyway to do this?

I'm sorry if this seems like a terrible juvenile question to ask, but I'm relatively new to programming.

Thanks,
Hayden

Comment: I think `c = new Console ();` won't compile. The constructor Console() is not visible

Answer (score 1):

- Java offers no standard way to access variables names in the way you require...
- At the point you create array the information is lost... It is pass by value, not by reference, so you're passing an array of the values 10, 4, 21, and 5 to Java

Therefore you need someway of linking the values and names...

- You could follow various enum, and switch hacks in other questions, but I believe these miss the point
- I'd recommend a more OO approach, with a class, called Person which stores name and value, together...
- Arrays.sort() doesn't know how to sort Person objects, so it either requires Person to implement `java.lang.Comparable`, or pass an optional `java.util.Comparator`, I've included an example of the later.

Code

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion {
    private class Person {
        private String name;
        private int value;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public Person(String name, int value) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private class Sorting {
        public Sorting() {
            Person[] people = { new Person("obi", 10), 
                                new Person("luke", 4),
                                new Person("vader", 21), 
                                new Person("palpatine", 5) };

            Arrays.sort(people, new Comparator<Person>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                    return o1.getValue() - o2.getValue();
                }
            });
            System.out.println(people[people.length - 1].getName());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new StackOverflowQuestion().new Sorting();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are `Person` and `Sorting` static?

Comment: I made Sorting static so it can be instantiated from main(String [] args) without having to do new StackOverflowQuestion().new Sorting(), but this is out of scope of your question, I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print variable name instead of value. Ideally in this way you can't. But you can try with something similar with `enums`. Also `c = new Console ();` will not compile if you are using `java.io.Console` you can't initialize this way since `Console` constructor is `private`

Eg:

```
public class Test {
public void Sorting() {
    int[] people = {Values.obi.getCode(), Values.luke.getCode(), Values.vader.getCode(), Values.palpatine.getCode()};
    Arrays.sort(people);
    System.out.println(Values.getEnum(people[people.length - 1]));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test s = new Test();
    s.Sorting();
}

public enum Values {
    obi(10), luke(4), vader(21), palpatine(5);

    private int code;

    Values(int i) {
        this.code = i;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public static Values getEnum(int code) {
        switch (code) {
            case 10:
                return obi;
            case 4:
                return luke;
            case 21:
                return vader;
            case 5:
                return palpatine;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`public class StackOverflowQuestion {

```
public void sorting() {
    final int obi = 10;
    final int luke = 4;
    final int vader = 21;
    final int palpatine = 5;
    int[] people = { obi, luke, vader, palpatine };
    Arrays.sort(people);
    // max value
    int max = people[people.length - 1];
    System.out.println("Max Value:" + max);
    switch (max) {
    case obi:
        System.out.println("Obi");
        break;
    case luke:
        System.out.println("Luke");
        break;
    case vader:
        System.out.println("Vader");
        break;
    case palpatine:
        System.out.println("Palpatine ");
        break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackOverflowQuestion s = new StackOverflowQuestion();
    s.sorting();
}
```

}`

Comment: This would not scale nicely to a hundred people would it.

Comment: yes, and you cannot declare hundred people as variable. I just answer your question with your exist code.

Answer (score -2):

You should use a String array instead of int array.

```
String[ ] people = {"obi", "luke", "vader", "palpatine"};
Arrays.sort(people);
System.out.println(people[people.length-1]);
```

**EDITED**
In that case you should use this strategy.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Person[] persons = new Person[4];
        persons[0] = new Person("obi", 10);
        persons[1] = new Person("luke", 4);
        persons[2] = new Person("vader", 21);
        persons[3] = new Person("palpatine ", 5);
    Arrays.sort(persons);
    System.out.println(persons[persons.length - 1].getName());
}
}
class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    private String name;
    private int number;
    public Person(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person otherPerson) {
        Person thisPerson = this;
        return thisPerson.getNumber() > otherPerson.getNumber() ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer. **Copy** the above code to `Test.java` file. @Adam